# можно ли в DevExpress "положить набок" таблицу(dxg:Tableview) или похожий компонент?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

суть вопроса в заголовке -- нужно чтобы хедеры шли перечислением слева по вертикали, а добавление новых записей было справа столбцом; если это возможно, то как? подскажите, где посмотреть пример, а то это не гуглиться  :(

**UPDATE** (по ответу Uranus'а):

1) в упомянутом коде VerticalGridControl.xaml.cs "как есть" содержится незначительная ошибка:

```
    void OnProcessUnboundColumnData(object sender, GridColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {
        IList itemsSource = (ItemsSource as IList);
        if (itemsSource == null) return;
        VerticalRowData row = Rows[e.ListSourceRowIndex];
        object item = itemsSource[Convert.ToInt32(e.Column.FieldName)];
        PropertyInfo itemProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty(row.RowName);
        if (itemProperty == null) return;
        if (e.IsGetData)
        {
            e.Value = itemProperty.GetValue(item, null );//!второй параметр вроде как необязательный, но без дописанного (,null) не работает
        }
        if (e.IsSetData)
        {
            itemProperty.SetValue(item, e.Value, null );//!третий параметр вроде как необязательный, но без дописанного (,,null) не работает
        }
    }
```

2) есть *неожиданное* *поведение* -- горизонтальные "столбцы" автоматически называются именами свойств объектов класса T из листа ItemSource< T >, т.о. когда мне *требуется*(увы) называть горизонтальные "столбцы" связными конструкциями слов русского языка это *беда* -- в принципе (хотя не стоит, конешно) имя св-ва может состоять из русских букв, но не может содержать пробелы -- я пока совершенно не представляю, как это обороть =((( неразрывные пробелы ожидаемо не прокатили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для представления данных в таком виде не получится просто взять и настроить обычный грид. Необходим компонент, который специально реализован таким образом, чтобы отображать колонки вертикально.

Такой DevExpress компонент есть не для всех платформ. Для WPF платформы пока нет. Пока что предоставляется решение в виде примера: [How to create a custom GridControl that represents columns horizontally in a way similar to the WinForms VerticalGrid control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4630/how-to-create-a-custom-gridcontrol-that-represents-columns-horizontally-in-a-way-similar).

Если в проекте требуются функции, которых не хватает в примере, можно связаться со службой поддержки через [онлайн сервис](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: большое спасибо, то что надо; есть пара важных моментов, обновил вопрос.